# Despite removing and greasing it, my pedal still won't rotate - I can't figure out why

Tags: repair, pedals

Yesterday out cycling on muddy farm roads, my right pedal seized up and stopped turning (the crank turns fine, but the pedal itself doesn't turn to stay parallel with the ground, making cycling difficult because my foot keeps coming off). I assume it got grit/mud in it - at one point the road was flooded and the bike got immersed up to the top of the chainring - but I've removed the pedal, rinsed, dried and oiled the threads, and replaced it, but it's still really stiff. I'm fairly confused as to why - there was no visible mud even before cleaning. Any thoughts? I used a generic bike oil - would getting penetrating oil help?

It's a new bike (Sirius X 3.0) - this is my 10th or so ride, no issues hitherto.
Edit: as per the comments/answers, I realised it is the locknut - it doesn’t appear to be removable as you can see in the image, and WD40 doesn’t appear to be helping. I suppose taking it back to the shop is the only thing to do if the pedal can’t be disassembled. [image: image of locknut]

Comment: If the pedal can't be disassembled and cleaned or adjusted (some pedals are not made to be serviced) it may be time for new pedals.

Comment: There might be a way to open the pedal from the other side. Check for a nut or screw at the top of the pedal on the outer side. It may not be obvious.

Comment: Note that the pedals that come with bikes really are just there for looks. They are built terribly.

Answer (score 5):

If it is a 10th ride on a new bike, I would take it to the bike shop. This might be some problem that is covered by the warranty.

---

Otherwise:

If you oiled the threads, it should not help much. Those threads just keep the pedal on the crank. There will also be other internal threads inside, but they keep the pedal together.

You have to disassemble the pedal, if it is at all possible, and inspect the bearings. Hopefully it will be enough to clean them and grease them. Better with a grease, not oil.

Penetrating oil, especially stuff like WD40, might get it released inside, but might also dissolve the grease.

Comment: There is a possibility that the lock nut for the cup & cone bearing in the pedal was loose and the cone tightened itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. I'm not keen on going to the shop if I can help it (Covidwise) so although I can't disassemble the pedal I'll try scrubbing and greasing it.